# How do I migrate projects from Unfuddle to GitHub?

Tags: github, migration, migrate-data

Unfuddle just increased their prices, i.e. the Compact plan went from $24 to $39, and the Micro plan also went from $9 to $15. That's a non-negligible change. They also limited some of the features int the entry Micro plan a while ago.

That $39/mo could buy a lot of GitHub private repositories, with tickets and all.

Is there an easy way to migrate projects from Unfuddle to GitHub, with tickets and repository?